# How to change the name, but not the value of a dynamically filled select list?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, getjson, selectlist

I have a select list that is dynamically filled with data from my database. But I don't want the users to see the real column names, so I created a extra column in my database called column_alias. What I want, is to show the column_alias names in the dropdown but keep the real values of column names.

This is how I'm filling the select list with the real column names at the moment:

```
function loadTables() {
        $.getJSON("dropdown_code/get_tables.php", success = function(data)
        {
            console.log('inside callback');
            var optionsTables = "";
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                {
                    optionsTables += "<option value='" + data[i] + "'>" + data[i] + "</option>";
                }

        $("#slctTable").append(optionsTables);
        $("#slctTable").change();
    }); 

}
```

And this is the code that get's the data outof my database:

```
<?PHP

    require "opendb.php";

    $query =    "select table_name 
                from db_tables 
                order by table_name";

    $data = pg_query($conn, $query);

    $table_names = array();

    while ($row = pg_fetch_array($data))
    {
        array_push($table_names, $row["table_name"]);
    }

    echo json_encode($table_names);

    require "closedb.php";
?>
```

**Update**

This is what my database table looks like:
[image]

So I want the table_alias to be visible in my select list, but I want the value to be table_name so it can interact with my database.

Comment: Changing the `<option />` value attribue can be done using `$(...).attr('value')`

Comment: But than it keeps the value and only changes the name?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What 'name' do you want change?

name attribute of select?
name attribute of option?
label of option?
placeholder for select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you will need to fetch the alias as well from the database.Change your server side code to the following.

```
<?PHP

require "opendb.php";

$query =    "select table_name,table_alias 
            from db_tables 
            order by table_name";

$data = pg_query($conn, $query);
$table_names = array();

while ($row = pg_fetch_array($data))
{
    array_push($table_names, $row);
}
echo json_encode($table_names);
require "closedb.php";
?>
```

Then in your client side code simply output the table_alias as option name and table_name as option value.

```
function loadTables() {
    $.getJSON("dropdown_code/get_tables.php", success = function(data)
    {
        console.log('inside callback');
        var optionsTables = "";
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            {
                optionsTables += "<option value='" + data[i]['table_name'] + "'>" + data[i]['table_alias'] + "</option>";
            }

    $("#slctTable").append(optionsTables);
    $("#slctTable").change();
}); 
}
```

Comment: Awesome that worked! Thanks a lot! I will mark you'r answer as the correct one.

Comment: Sorry! It's not clear what you are asking. i think it's a problem of not accessing the object correctly. You have to specify the attribute name. Take a look at this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: Never mind I fixed it. But thanks for the response, I will delete the other comment.

Answer (score 0):

**html**

```
<select id="xoxo_select">
  <option value="foo_value">foo</option>
  <option value="xoxo_value">xoxo</option>
</select>
```

**js**

```
$('#xoxo_select option[value="xoxo_value"]').text('bar'); // change name of option
$('#xoxo_select option[value="xoxo_value"]').attr('value', 'bar_value'); // change value of option
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tg126u7g/

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle. I undertand what you'r doing. But I need to implement the solution in my script and I don't know if that's possible because it's a dynamic approach and not a static one like yours?

Answer (score 0):

Change in fetch data from DB:

```
<?PHP

require "opendb.php";

$query =    "select table_name,table_alis 
            from db_tables 
            order by table_name";

$data = pg_query($conn, $query);

$table_names = array();
 $i=0;
while ($row = pg_fetch_array($data))
{

    array_push($table_names[$i], $row["table_name"]);
    $i++;
}

echo json_encode($table_names);

    require "closedb.php";
?>
```

Then Change in javascript code:

```
optionsTables += "<option value='" + data[i][0] + "'>" + data[i][1] + "</option>";
```